# JPA - delete a child from OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa

In a **@OneToMany** relationship if I want to remove a child, do I need to explicitly delete that child from parent's collection as well or just deleting the child will suffice?

For instance, `Person` and `Phone`. Each person has many phone numbers. If I want to delete one phone number from a person is this enough:

```
EntityManager.remove(phone);
```

Or I need to to this beforehand:

```
Person.getPhone().remove(phone);
```

Not to mention, the **CascadeType** is set to **MERGE**.

Comment: I want to understand it rather than trying it.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful and friendly comment. I had no idea that there is a documentation.

Comment: @LutzHorn, it all says `if parent is`. I'm asking to delete the child.

Comment: Then read all of http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA

Comment: OK Danke schon my helpful friend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to remove the `Phone` explicitly from the `phones` collection, it's not enough to remove it with the `EntityManager`.

From the other side, it might be sufficient to use `orphanRemoval`, so if you remove an entity from a collection, it gets automatically deleted. Something like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person", orphanRemoval="true")
private List<Phone> phones;
```

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/index.html

`Cascade.REMOVE` only removes the child entity if the parent entity is removed as well. `Cascase.MERGE` has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: You are right, the cascadeType does not matter in this use case. The reference to the entity will still be valid and found in referencing collections, it will be just in the removed state.

Comment: Exactly. I think an exception with `Referential integrity constraint violation` will be thrown if you don't remove it from the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if MERGE is enough to get entities deleted cascaded, you will probably have to also define DELETE cascading and depending on how the data is mapped (with or without a secondary table in between) it might even be necessary to apply orphan removal too.

If you don't apply cascading for deletion but rather use a JPA query or an entityManager.remove(), then it is certainly a good idea to manually evict it from the oneToMany collection as well. The reason is simple: you may manually remove it from the database, but that doesn't mean it automagically gets removed from the collection too so for the lifetime of the parent entity, it will still be referencing an entity which is not supposed to exist anymore. Things get weird when you then also accidentally change the state of said entity.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about removal from the other side.